# adblock - block one option from select list

Tags: html, select, block, adblock

I can't find a way to block one option from select list.

For example I have on page:

```
 <select name="test_select">
   <option value="1">Something I don't need</option>
   <option value="2">Something I still need</option>
 </select>
```

I use filter `##option[value="1"]`

So.. seems that filter don't block initial state of select. After page loaded default value "I don't need" still displayed.

When I'm trying to select another option(s) - the first option disappear from the list which is fine, but still problem for me that initially unneeded option shown after page loaded.

Is there a way to block(remove) this option completely?

Comment: What do you mean by "block"?

Comment: I mean - completely remove it from the web page. So.. I don't want to see this option at all. Probably it was better to name this question as "adblock - block(remove) one option from select list"

Answer (score 0):

The filter works as expected because it's supposed to hide the `<option>` element, not the `<select>` element. If you want to hide the `<select>` element but only if it has a certain value, you'd need to wait for parent selectors to (hopefully) arrive with CSS4. Those would allow you to write the filter as

`##!select > option[value="1"]:checked` (based on the syntax in the [W3C working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject))
`##select:has(> option[value="1"]:checked)` (based on the syntax in the [CSSWG editor's draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational))